# possible to get the square coordinates using imgAreaSelect and Google Maps?

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I had seen a site do this a long time ago...

Is it possible to 'crop' an area in GoogleMaps using imgAreaSelect (http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/) or jCrop and get the coordinates for the square from it?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a Google Maps API site, which I assume you're doing, it would be easier to use the [Drawing Tools Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#drawing_tools) to draw a rectangle and get the coordinates that way.